# How can i add sub menu in navigation drawer for xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, navigation-drawer, submenu

I want to display sub-menu for one item which in the navigation drawer. I want to add 5 sub-menu items for one item which is in the navigation drawer.

Which one is the best and easiest way to add the submenu for the item? And I want to use this sub-menu in android and IOS applications.

**MasterDetailPage.cs :**

```
 public MainMasterDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = GetMasterPageLists();
            this.IsPresented = false;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new DashboardTabbedPage());

        }

        private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MasterPageList)e.SelectedItem;

            if (item.Title == "Settings")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "vssSQLite.db3");
                SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
                db.DropTable<LoginSqlLiteM>();
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            }
        }
        List<MasterPageList> GetMasterPageLists()
        {
            return new List<MasterPageList>
            {
                new MasterPageList() { Title = "Settings", Icon = "settings.png" },
                new MasterPageList() { Title = "Logout", Icon = "logout.png" },

            };
        }
    }
```

**MasterDetailPage.Xaml :**

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VSS.MasterPages"
                  xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:VSS.Pages"
                  IsPresented="False"
             x:Class="VSS.MasterPages.MainMasterDetailPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="☰">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                <StackLayout Margin="25,10,25,0" Padding="0,15,0,15">
                    <Image Source="VSSIcon.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80"></Image>
                    <Label Text="Sched.ly" TextColor="#1CA9FF" FontSize="Large"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                    <Label Text="Always on Time " TextColor="#1CA9FF" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Italic"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"  
                  RowHeight="60"  
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"  
                  ItemSelected="OnMenuSelected"  
                  BackgroundColor="#2196F3">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                 Padding="20,10,0,10"  
                                 Spacing="20">

                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"  
                                     WidthRequest="30"  
                                     HeightRequest="30"  
                                     VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  
                                     FontSize="Medium"  
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                     TextColor="White"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:DashboardTabbedPage/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

[image: Please click here to see the navigation drawer image]

I want to display the sub-menu items for `Settings` item. How can I do that submenu for `settings`item?

Help me.

Comment: use list view with grouping http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview

Comment: Tried..Getting so many exceptions

Comment: @logeshpalani98 Please check this link once.

https://github.com/priyam1996/NavigationSubMenuProject

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use Listview with grouping header like [james did in here](https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options you can use a Bindable Layout and set padding to it or a ListView / Collection View nested.

Refer to my [blog here to know how to use Bindable Layout](https://xdevlogs.com/2020/01/04/bindable-layout-xamarin-forms/) if you are going to use that.

Otherwise, if your requirement is to use it like a expandable option, then please refer the below links that might help you in achieving your requirement.

- [Expandable ListView App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expendable-listview-app/). Download working demo from the top of this blog.
- [Open source plugin for Expandable ListView](https://github.com/my-jabin/ExpandableListView-Xamarin)
- [Xamarin forms expandable listview](http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview). [Demo here](https://github.com/Robbie188/XamarinFormsExpandableList).

Comment: I tried expandable list view app..It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Priyanka: Added some demo links. Please check.

Comment: I already saw those articles..Those are very confused to implement in the navigation drawer.

Comment: Please check this link once.

https://github.com/priyam1996/NavigationSubMenuProject